Powershell: convert to csv sorting two columns
In this script the data isn't sorting by the first column computer, and THEN the program name. What is going wrong there?
$data = Get-RemoteProgram -ComputerName (Get-Content -Path C:\PowerShell\complist.txt) -ExcludeProgram (Get-Content -Path C:\PowerShell\applist.txt) | Where-Object {($_.ProgramName -notmatch 'KB\d+|Microsoft .NET|Microsoft Visual|Intel|Windows Driver Package')} | sort Computer,ProgramName
$data | export-csv -path C:\PowerShell\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
$data | export-csv -path C:\PowerShell\outputappend.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append

Sorts by computer OR programname, but not one and then the other.

Did you perhaps mean to write sort ComputerName,ProgramName instead of sort Computer,ProgramName?

Oof, that's my bad. Excel cropped the first column down because our computer names are smaller, which made the column title look exactly like "Computer". Didn't even realize until I manually looked and pulled the column apart that it is "ComputerName". Fixing it in the script made it work. Thanks for thinking of that.
